# Mouse click to select a word in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

In Visual Studio, SQL Server Management Studio, etc I can hold Ctrl down and click to select a whole word. I find this makes copying and pasting multiple words much faster. I can hold Ctrl down, click a word, press c, click somewhere else, press v, repeat.

I'm wondering if this functionality is possible in Sublime Text 2 (probably with another key since Ctrl is already used for multiple selections).

Comment: This post details a method I couldn't get it to work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694823/ctrl-click-binding-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 4):

`Ctrl+D` selects the whole Word in Sublime-Text 2. As a bonus, if you press you press it multiple times you can select different occurences of the word and do multiline editing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your OS is Windows create a file named "Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap" in User directory (which can be accessed through menu Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Browse Packages) and put this in it

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "words"}
    }
]
```

Change modifiers anyway you like and done.

Answer (score 0):

Here, double click on a word selects the whole word (at least for a `.txt` file).

Comment: Yeah that works everywhere but I don't find that quite as fast